# Does there exist a "Möbius cloth"?

Tags: algebraic-topology

If such a cloth exists, then one should no more worry about the orientation of our clothes, which troubled me sometimes. :P
Thus I am wondering

> Does there exist a non-orientable surface with $3$ holes in $\mathbb R^3?$

Maybe this is not precisely equivalent with the imagination, but intuitively this is what one thinks at first.
And I know that the Möbius strip has one hole.
In any case, every help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your definition of genus?

Comment: The number of holes?

Comment: Nah. That only works for closed, orientable surfaces. A cylinder has genus $0$, by the way.

Comment: OK, sorry for using a concept that I am not familiar with. What if we say that it has $3$ holes?

Comment: We could take a regular shirt and sew a projective plane or several into it. There are lots of different such surfaces. Look up *connected sum*.

Comment: How can sewing a projective plane into a regular shirt achieve our goal? Of course a cloth with a Möbius strip joined is not what we wanted: we still have to distinguish between the two sides of the cloth. Sorry for my poor knowledge in algebraic topology.

Comment: You can also attach a Möbius strip in the same way. Your shirt can just have a tiny non-orientable piece within a 1 sq in region and it will still be non-orientable.  The same is true of a Möbius strip, by the way: You can make it be a perfectly fine cylinder for all but 1/100 sq in, where the twist occurs and makes the whole surface one-sided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People make mobius scarves. Also since our surface area is orientable, then if we were to wear a nonorientable surface, there would have to be some kind of nonsmoothness involved (ie, some kind of fold against your skin), which would be annoying as hell.